# Bootstrap Displaying PopOver Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Bootstrap popup dynamically. I am using the following code but it does not show anything.

```
function showDictionaryPopup(term) {

// create popover div
var popoverDiv = $("<div>");

popoverDiv.attr("data-toggle","popover");
popoverDiv.attr("data-content","This is a test");
popoverDiv.addClass("row");

popoverDiv.popover();

$("body").append(popoverDiv);

}
```

I do not get any errors or anything..

Comment: Please post JS Fiddle or other live example of your revised version

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are appending the div to the DOM but never letting the popover be shown. Try calling popoverDiv.popover('show');

You may also want to add some content to the popover. All the available options can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Thanks! Now the popup is showing. But it does not show correctly. It does not appear to be floating. I am sure I am missing the css classes.